# How to take an Input integer from HTM? - Arduino / NodeMCU ESP32

Tags: html, web, arduino, esp32, nodemcu

Hi im currently doing Servo NodeMCU controlling. my plan is to create an Input Box where i can type, then whatever number i type will be use as servo angle using Webserver or 194.168.4.1 or so on. (ex: i type 90, servo angle will be 90) the problem i si do not know how to get it. here is the code:

```
#include<Servo.h>
Servo ServoPin;
int angle = 0;
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiAP.h>

#define ServoPin 34;   // Set the GPIO pin where you connected your test LED or comment this line out if your dev board has a built-in LED
// Set these to your desired credentials.
const char *ssid = "XXXXXX";
const char *password = "XXXXXX";

WiFiServer server(80);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Configuring access point...");
  pinMode(ServoPin,OUTPUT);
  // You can remove the password parameter if you want the AP to be open.
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
  server.begin();

  Serial.println("Server started");
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("New Client.");           // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character

          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println();

            // the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
            client.print("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            client.print("<html>");
            client.print("<body>");
            client.print("<p>Change the text of the text field, and then click the button below.</p>"); //
            client.print("INPUT NUMBER: <input type='number' id='servo'>"); //in this area, I WILL TYPE number 0-255.
            client.print("<button type='button' '>Go</button>");
            ServoPin.attach(number);  //the area where i will assign the servo to the angle i type.
          
            // break out of the while loop:
            break;
          } else {    // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
    }
    
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client Disconnected.");
  }
}
```

So as you can see in client.print"INPUT NUMBER.... so on line, that is the place where my code will design an input box. the problem is it is inside a " " or double quotation mark. i wonder what should i do to get the 'number' input then use it on ServoPin.attach(number);

im very beginner on HTML(zero actually) because i dont have knowledge here yet. this code is mostly taken from internet w3school website then i modify it a bit to Servo controlling. so im really hoping that someone can tell me how to do it....

Board: Node32
actual Board: NodeMCU ESP 32

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp you have to create form to send those values to another page (but it migh be the same page).

Comment: Read or run the sketch [WebUpdate](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/WebUpdate/WebUpdate.ino) that came with ESP8266 arduino installation to understand how to setup a web server and html form.

Answer (score 0):

Here is web server code that parses two variables from a GET response of a HTML form, I suppose it should be no problem to adopt it for your needs: [http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/WebServerST](https://Here%20is%20web%20server%20code%20that%20parses%20two%20variables,%20but%20it%20should%20be%20no%20problem%20to%20do%205.%20http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/WebServerST)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31486083)

Answer (score 0):

Hey so this is the how I do this, I've made a form in your html that would take the input and send a get request to the server and can be dealt with there. this is the process:

- input put into form, sent to server in get request.
- the get request is send stored char by char in header variable.
- if statement checks if the parameter is in the header. The string is searched for the value and the value is saved into a string.

good luck this should work.

```
#include<Servo.h>
Servo ServoPin;
int angle = 0;
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiAP.h>

#define ServoPin 34;   // Set the GPIO pin where you connected your test LED or comment this line out if your dev board has a built-in LED
// Set these to your desired credentials.
const char *ssid = "XXXXXX";
const char *password = "";

WiFiServer server(80);
String header; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Configuring access point...");
  pinMode(ServoPin,OUTPUT);
  // You can remove the password parameter if you want the AP to be open.
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
  server.begin();

  Serial.println("Server started");
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("New Client.");           // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();// read a byte, then
        header += c;             //write request to the header
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character

          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println();

            if (header.indexOf("input1=") >= 0) { //if input1 is in the header then...
              Serial.println(header);
              String input_string = "";
              int reqEnd = header.indexOf(" HTTP/1.1");   
              for (int n = 16; n < reqEnd; ++n) {  //put the input value from the header to the variable
                input_string += header[n];
              }
              
              Serial.println(input_string);
            }             
            

            // the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
            client.print("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            client.print("<html>");
            client.print("<body>");

            client.print("<form action=\"/get\">"); //added a form to take a text input and send a get request.
            client.print("input1: <input type=\"text\" name=\"input1\">");
            client.print("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">");
            client.print("</form><br>");         
            ServoPin.attach(number);  //the area where i will assign the servo to the angle i type.
          
            // break out of the while loop:
            break;
          } else {    // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
    }
    
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client Disconnected.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "ESPAsyncWebServer.h"

const char* ssid = "yourNetworkName";
const char* password =  "yourNetworkPass";

AsyncWebServer server(80);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){

    int paramsNr = request->params();
    Serial.println(paramsNr);

    for(int i=0;i<paramsNr;i++){

        AsyncWebParameter* p = request->getParam(i);
        Serial.print("Param name: ");
        Serial.println(p->name());
        Serial.print("Param value: ");
        Serial.println(p->value());
        Serial.println("------");
    }

    request->send(200, "text/plain", "message received");
  });

  server.begin();
}

void loop()
    {}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).